# Stacked plots from a multi-index data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I know how to plot something like this:

```
               SEASON1  SEASON2  SEASON3
area                                    
A   299.0  2.0  257.0
B   13.0  33.0  198.0
C   22044.0  2.0  22.0
```

Using

```
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=90, edgecolor='black')
df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, edgecolor='black')
```

Resulting in:

[stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC2i.png)

[transposed stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbKR.png)

I'm having hard time to obtain the same (or even better looking) plots  for the following `df` which is representing the original `df` but made more elegantly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663504/pandas-python-vertical-weeks-binned-to-horizontal-buckets).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to unstack your dataframe, and change the name of the columns.

You can do so by doing :

```
df.unstack()
  .rename(columns = {
            "2016Q1" : "Season 1",
            "2016Q2" : "Season 2",
            "2016Q3" : "Season 3",
        })
```

You can find examples on the documentation about what [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) does, and how it is doing it. As for the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method, it takes a mapping to convert your names from something to something else.

I didn't try to make your example work, but I took an example from the unstack documentation above.

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('one', 'a'), ('one', 'b'),
                                   ('two', 'a'), ('two', 'b')])

df = pd.DataFrame( np.arange(1.0, 5.0), index=index, columns=['hi'])
print(df)
#         hi
# one a  1.0
#     b  2.0
# two a  3.0
#     b  4.0

df = df.unstack(level = -1)
       .rename(columns = {
            "a" : "Season 1",
            "b" : "Season 2"
        })
print(df)
#           hi         
#     Season 1 Season 2
# one      1.0      2.0
# two      3.0      4.0
```

There could be a better way to handle the "hi" above your DataFrame but you can just `select` it, and it'll disappear.

```
print( s['hi'] )
     Season 1  Season 2
one       1.0       2.0
two       3.0       4.0
```

Comment: Sweet. Tested. Working! So I'm concluding that the best practice is perhaps is not to deal with the original multi-index `df` right? If so, I will go and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @KyleDickson Well, I didn't make a lot of research on the subject but thinking about it, usually plots are 2D, and a DataFrame is a 2D object. Multi Index are useful to handle 2D+ data. I don't think pandas multi index handles plots on a 3D level though. I don't think it has to do with best practice or anything there.

Comment: @KyleDickson If you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25401328/8003790), you can see that you could decide to plot your multi index on different axes. It would just be a different choice. :) Here, you shouldn't be thinking about best practice but possibilities : can I plug a 3D object into a 2D plotter ? :p