# how to make stacked plots for dataframe with multiple index in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have trade export data which is collected weekly. I intend to make stacked bar plot with `matplotlib` but I have little difficulties managing pandas dataframe with multiple indexes. I looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386870/pandas-plotting-with-multi-index) but not able to get what I am expecting. Can anyone suggest a possible way of doing this in python? Seems I made the wrong data aggregation and I think I might use `for loop` to iterate year then make a stacked bar plot on a weekly base. Does anyone know how to make this easier in `matplotlib`? any idea?

**reproducible data and my attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/0eb9d60374c8a0c17449eef4583705d7/raw/edea1777466284f2958ffac6cafb86683e08a65e/mydata.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)

nn = df.set_index(['year','week'])
nn.drop("weekly", axis=1, inplace=True)

f, a = plt.subplots(3,1)
nn.xs('2018').plot(kind='bar',ax=a[0])
nn.xs('2019').plot(kind='bar',ax=a[1])
nn.xs('2020').plot(kind='bar',ax=a[2])
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

this attempt didn't work for me. instead of explicitly selecting years like `2018`, `2019`, ..., is there any more efficient to make stacked bar plots for dataframe with multiple indexes? Any thoughts?

**desired output**

this is the [desired stacked bar plot for year of `2018` as an example](https://ibb.co/0ypg4yM)

how should I get my desired stacked bar plot? Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
nn.groupby(level=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

or to prevent year as tuple in x axis:

```
for n, g in nn.groupby(level=0):
    g.loc[n].plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

---

## Update per request in comments

```
for n, g in nn.groupby(level=0):
    ax = g.loc[n].plot.bar(stacked=True, title=f'{n} Year', figsize=(8,5))
    ax.legend(loc='lower center')
```

---

## Change layout position

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
axi = iter(ax)
for n, g in nn.groupby(level=0):
    axs = next(axi)
    g.loc[n].plot.bar(stacked=True, title=f'{n}', figsize=(15,8), ax=axs)
    axs.legend(loc='lower center')
```

Comment: This would pass `2018` to the x-ticks as well. So the label will read `(2018,1),...` Is there a direct way to drop that?

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks for the updated attempt. How should we control `figsize`, legend position, and add each year+ some string as a title?

Comment: shouldn't `figsize` be passed to `subplots`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I think you can do it either way.  I am not really certain though.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `loc` instead of `xs`:

```
f, a = plt.subplots(3,1)
for x, ax in zip(nn.index.unique('year'),a.ravel()):
    nn.loc[x].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

Comment: this is super! how should I control legend position  (add one the top of each stacked plot) and add each distinct year + some string as the title? also, how can we keep the distance between each subplot?

Comment: Have a look at the [document](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) for `subplots`. You can add title for each subplot inside the `for` loop, e.g. `ax.set_title('some title')`.

Comment: @Adam You can use `...plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, title=f'{n} Year')`